# Are all these verbs in Rom. 8:29-30 in aorist?

Tags: romans, grammar

Are all the high-lightened verbs in the passage below in aorist?

> For whom he **did foreknow**, he also **did predestinate** [to be] conformed
>   to the image of his Son, that he might be the firstborn among many
>   brethren. Moreover whom he **did predestinate**, them he also **called**: and
>   whom he **called**, them he also **justified**: and whom he **justified**, them he
>   also **glorified**. (Rom. 8:29-30)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Yes, all of the verbs are aorist.

---

In fact, they are all identical in all of the following ways:

Part of Speech: Verb 
**Tense: Aorist** 
Mood: Indicative 
Voice: Active 
Person: 3rd Person 
Number: Singular

---

Here they are, for reference:

- προέγνω (he foreknew)
- προώρισεν (he predestined)
- προώρισεν (he predestined #2)
- ἐκάλεσεν (he called)
- ἐκάλεσεν (he called #2)
- ἐδικαίωσεν (he justified)
- ἐδικαίωσεν (he justified #2)
- ἐδόξασεν (he glorified)

Answer (score 0):

many speak of 'glorified' as already done in the mind of God.  each of these acts are already done in the mind of God.  other verses use other terms ... verbs speaking of salvation and arrange them in different orders.  such texts are not presented as 'steps from a - z in the great work of salvation'.  2 Tim 1:9 for example.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.